# How do I loop through an array in Vue half the amount of times as there are items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js, v-for

I have an array of data:

```
[
  {
    type: select, 
    options: [foo, bar], 
    label: foo, 
    required: true
  }, 
  {
    type: text, 
    options: [],
    label: bar, 
    required: false
  }, 
  {
    type: checkbox, 
    options: [], 
    label: baz, 
    required: true
  }
]
```

and a Vue template:

```
<b-row>
  <b-col>
    <label :for="{{label}}">{{ label }}<span class="required" v-if="required"/></label>
    {{ checks type and injects proper form element here }}
  </b-col>
</b-row>
```

**I'm trying to figure out how best to loop through each object, and place each one into its own `<b-col>`, with only two columns per row so that it looks similar to the following structure:**

```
<b-row>
  <b-col>
    <label for="size">foo<span class="required" v-if="required"/></label>
    <b-form-select id="size">
      <options>foo</options>
      <options>bar</options>
    </b-form-select>
  </b-col>
  <b-col>
    <label for="size">bar<span class="required" v-if="required"/></label>
    <b-form-text id="size"/>
  </b-col>
</b-row>
<b-row>
  <b-col>
    <label for="size">baz<span class="required" v-if="required"/></label>
    <b-form-select id="size"/>
  </b-col>
    <label for="size">barbaz<span class="required" v-if="required"/></label>
    <b-form-select id="size"/>
  </b-col>
</b-row>
...etc.
```

I'm struggling to find the best approach to accomplish this cleanly and in a vue-like manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just iterate through the array, place each element inside a `b-col` and specify the width of each of those columns to be 50%, like this:

```
<b-row>
    <b-col v-for="item in array" sm="6">
        ...do something with item
    </b-col>
</b-row>
```

`sm="6"` tells bootstrap to use the amount of space equal to 6 columns (i.e. 50%)
I am not sure about vue-bootstrap, but the bootstrap documentation states:

> If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of
>   extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#column-wrapping

Comment: Thank you @puelo, this does in fact solve my problem.  I'm marking it as correct and I appreciate the swift reply, but I am curious if anyone has an answer to my original question also.  I'm always interested in learning new ways of accomplishing things.